# 'Drunk' input from readline, OK from other programs (reading smart meters P1 port)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, readline, pyserial

I'm new to Python and want to read my smart meters P1 port using a Raspberry Pi and Python. Problem: the input looks like some component is drunk.
I'm sure it's pretty simple to fix, but after several hours of searching and trying, had to seek help.

When reading the P1 port with CU etc. everything is fine so the hardware etc. is OK. Using a serial to USB converter from dx.com ([this one](http://dx.com/p/usb-to-rs232-serial-port-adapter-transparent-green-24512?item=4))

Command and (part of) the output: **cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 9600 --parity=none**

```
0-0:96.1.1(205A414246303031363631323463949271)
1-0:1.8.1(03118.000*kWh)
```

However, when trying to read it from Python, the input becomes gibberish (but at least sort of consistant):

```
0-0:96.±.±(²05A´±´²´630303±39363±3²3´639·3±3²©
±-0:±.¸.±(03±±¸.000ªë×è©
```

How to fix this? The code I'm using is:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff=0
ser.rtscts=0
ser.timeout=20
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0"

ser.close()
ser.open()
print ("Waiting for P1 output on "  + ser.portstr)

counter=0
#read 20 lines    
while counter < 20:
    print ser.readline()
    counter=counter+1

try:
    ser.close()
    print ("Closed serial port.")
except:
    sys.exit ("Couldn't close serial port.")
```

Have already tried messing with baudrate etc. but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Did you try every possible value for the parity setting, while keeping other settings as they are? It looks like a parity issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UPDATE*: found a workaround by replacing the naughty characters.
This may work for others with the same problem, but I dont know if the bad characters are exactly the same. So the replacement part may need some work to make it work for others.

It's not exactly a solution as the incoming telegram is still messed up, but the following code will work around that. My telegram is completely clean now.

Relevant part of the code I'm using now:

```
#Define 2 variables
P1_numbers = {'±':'1', '²':'2', '´':'4', '·':'7', '¸':'8'}
P1_rest    = {'¯':'/', 'ª':'*', '©':')', 'Æ':'F', 'ë':'k', '×':'W', 'è':'h', 'í':'m'}

# Define function to read the telegram. Calls a function to clean it.
def P1_read(stack):
    counter = 0
    while counter < TelegramLength:
        stack.append(P1_clean(ser.readline()))
        counter=counter+1
    return stack

# Define function to clean up P1 output
def P1_clean(line):
    for i, j in P1_numbers.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(i, j)
    for i, j in P1_rest.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(i, j)
    return line
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the `serial` module, but I noticed that your `cu` command assumes there is no parity bit (`--parity=none`), but your python script assumes there is an even parity bit (`ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN`).  I would try

```
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
```

And if there's no parity bit, you'll also probably want

```
ser.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I quess you have a smart meter with P1 protocol: DSMR 3.0?
Then these are the correct serial port settings, which you already had:

```
serialport = serial.Serial(  # Configure Serial communication port
                            baudrate = 9600,
                            timeout  = 11,
                            bytesize = serial.SEVENBITS,
                            parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN,
                            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE )
```

Probably some encoding or interpretation of the data is going wrong at your side. Here is an other method the read the smart meter:

To make the readout of the p1 protocol as easy as possible I'd suggest to use TextIOWrapper, this way you can read the serial port with the readline method. The "!" always ends the P1 telegram, so that can be used to detect the end of the message. when a full telegram has been received, the telegram can be processed. Example:

```
import io
p1port = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(serialport, buffer_size=1), newline='\n', encoding='ascii')

P1Message = []

while True:
    try:
         rawline = self.p1port.readline()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
         print "Encode error on readline"

    if '!' in rawline:
        # Process your P1Message here

        P1Message = [] # Clear message, wait for new one
    else:
        P1Message.append(rawline)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP is looooong gone, but the problem is of sufficiently general interest, so here's a fresh answer. User @Brionius is right: A look at the bit patterns involved shows that it's definitely a parity problem. Here's how to inspect the bit pattern of the characters `"1"` and `"±"`:

```
>>> "{0:b}".format(ord("1"))
'110001'
>>> "{0:b}".format(ord("±"))
'10110001'
```

Get it? The characters are getting corrupted by having their high (8th) bit turned on. Or you can see this by setting the high bit of ascii `"1"`:

```
>>> chr(ord("1") | 0b10000000)
'±'
```

Now, `"1", "2"` and `"4"` have three bits set (odd parity), and are corrupted. `"0", "3", "5",` etc. have even parity (2 or 4 bits set), and are preserved. So the communication channel is using even parity, which is not decoded properly at the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also in the context of the P1 Smart Meter port, and it took me quite a while to find it.

'cu' was displaying the data correctly, but Python wasn't (nor were some other programs). Apparently the parity bit is somehow not handled correctly. The following solves this problem:

```
p1_raw = ser.readline()
print 'raw:', p1_raw

decoded = ''.join(chr(ord(ch) & 0x7f) for ch in p1_raw)
print 'decoded:', decoded
```

I still find it strange that this is happening, because this was actually happening when I was trying to read the output of a Smart Meter for the second time. I already had a script successfully monitoring another Smart Meter at a different house for a couple of years and I never ran into this problem.

Perhaps there's a small difference in the USB-Serial adapters that causes this?!?